# How would I make my chain "Metamask compatible"

Tags: metamask, wallets, blockchain-interoperation, rust

I'm currently working on a rust blockchain project and we are weeks until minimal test net,
we have CLI wallet and network will support EVM on the real test net. We have rpc api and I would like to add section for metamask eg /api/metamask/ and what calls do I need for it.
My crypto uses same secp256k1 as ethereum.
Also I want to add a note that I have tried contacting metamask but they did not respond.

Comment: Supporting the standard web3 JSON RPC should be enough https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API. To known exactly what commands are needed you could use ganache to log the command sends by metamask to the ganache rpc server.

Comment: Can you post a question so I can approve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supporting the standard web3 JSON RPC should be enough https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API.

To known exactly what commands are required you could use ganache to log the command sends by Metamask to the ganache rpc server.

Ganache has a command line option `-v` to log RPC requests and answers.